# passing data with nodejs/mongodb to the frontend (undefined on the browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I would like to get data from a mongodb database and pass it to the frond.
I wrote this function it works in the console i get an array that contains some elements but on the browser i get **undefined**. I use nodejs(express, ejs) and mongodb.

```
getAllOrders: function(companyName) {
    client.connect().then((client)=>{
         let db = client.db('data')
         db.collection('order').find({companyName:companyName}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result.map(a => a.orderIdem))) // output all orderIdems
        });
    });
}
```

//App.js

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
    let orderItem = await db.getAllOrders("SuperTrader");
    console.log(orderItem); // here i get a response
    res.render('index', {
        orderItem: orderItem,
    });
});
```

// frontend 
//index.ejs

```
   <h2>Variable</h2>
   <p><%= orderItem %></p>
```

//orderItem[0] also doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing you are returning from the function. try this:

```
getAllOrders: async function(companyName) {
    return client.connect().then((client)=>{
         let db = client.db('data')
         return await db.collection('order').find({companyName:companyName});
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have saved my day